# Iterate on Json between different dictionaries

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, for-loop

For a Video Editing application, our program outputs to a Json file the below data:

```
{
    "video_element": [
        {
            "file_name": [
                "clip01.mp4"
            ],
            "properties": [
                {
                    "first_frame": 1,
                    "start_frame": 1,
                    "last_frame": 700,
                }
            ],
            "vfx": "none"
        },
        {
            "file_name": [
                "clip02.mp4"
            ],
            "properties": [
                {
                    "first_frame": 702,
                    "start_frame": 703,
                    "last_frame": 1486,
                }
            ],
            "vfx": "none"
        }
    ]
}
```

We want to add an "Import" functionality, which will create new Clips, every time a user Imports a Json file, having the above structure. For example, every "file_name" is the path of the clip, and the "properties" the values in order to place the created clip in the corresponding location in times/frames.

While we can create a single clip, the issue is we cannot create 2 clips (clip01 + clip02) as the above data showcases.

We want to use a for loop, to look up for each entry dynamically, based on the "file_name", but we are hardcoding the path under our "for loop" to look for the "file_name" with:

```
data['video_element'][0]['file_name']
```

So since it's 0, it's always returning the first dictionary, with "file_name" clip01.mp4.
How can the loop get all the values for all the different dictionaries where "file_name" is not empty, without having to specify the array value?

We also tried by using:

```
data['video_element'][:].items()
```

Comment: `file_names = [video_element['file_name'] for video_element in data['video_element']]`

Comment: Will the `file_name` list ever have more than 1 element?

Comment: @flakes I'll give this a try and update back, thank you for the possible solution.

Comment: @Unmitigated No, "file_name" will always point to 1 single path per dictionary, therefore no 2nd element will exist.

Comment: But it's possible for there to be no `file_name` property?

Comment: @Unmitigated The "file_name" key will always exist, what is possible, is for the value to be an empty string "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get all the non-empty filenames:

```py
filenames = [o["file_name"][0] for o in data["video_element"] if o["file_name"][0]]
```

Comment: Can use an assignment expression to make that more terse. `filenames = [f for o in data["video_element"] if (f := o["file_name"][0])]`

Comment: @flakes That's true, but it does leave the variable `f` lying around after the comprehension.

Comment: It would, definitely a downside, but it is specifically highlighted as a valid pattern from the pep https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#simplifying-list-comprehensions

Comment: Thank you @Unmitigated for sharing your input, as the list comprehension solved our issue!

Comment: Thank you @flakes for your valuable and quick input into this issue, much appreciated!